# dynamically added checkbox input fields are not submitted with the form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that contains a couple of checkbox input fields added the fields are added within the `<form>` tag and filled after some dropdown menu changes. The problem is that the fields are not submitted with the rest of static input fields! the code is as follows:

```
success: function(records){
    $("#emps_table").empty();
    $("#emps_table").append('<tr><td></td><td>Emp ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Position</td></tr>');
    $.each(records, function(key, value){
        $("#emps_table").append('<tr><td><input type=checkbox class="emps_l" name=emp_chk[] checked value='+value["id"]+'></td><td>'+value["id"]+'</td><td>'+value["name"]+'</td><td>'+value['job']+'</td></tr>');
    });

}
```

Comment: $("#emps_table").append('<tr><td><input type=checkbox class="emps_l" name=emp_chk[] checked value='+value.id+'></td><td>'+value.id+'</td><td>'+value.name+'</td><td>'+value.job+'</td></tr>'); try this

Comment: Check if generated html is properly correct.

Comment: try adding quotes on the value of name attribute: name="emp_chk[]"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I think Syntax might be the problem

```
$("#emps_table").append("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' class='emps_l' name='emp_chk[]' checked='checked' value='"+value["id"]+"' ></td><td>"+value["id"]+"</td><td>"+value["name"]+"</td><td>"+value['job']+"</td></tr>");
```

Comment: Syntax has got no problem, I can get the with alert($(".emps_l").val()); but when I put it in a $.each loop it says that: object HTMLInputElement and here is the code of loop:$.each($(".emps_l"),function(index,value){       
           v_test += value+',';
           
            });           v_test variable is also declared upper and when I assign to it the value of index then it get it correctly but instead of getting the value it shows:object HTMLInputElement